# Interprete log(y) changes in regression

Tags: data-transformation, interpretation, logarithm

I oriented at this explanation of interpreting statistical outcomes:

[http://www.princeton.edu/~otorres/Stata/](http://www.princeton.edu/%7Eotorres/Stata/)
ln(Y)=B0 + B1*X + u ~ A change in X by one unit (∆X=1) is associated with a (exp(B1) - 1)*100 % change in Y

I a regression output Y, which originally is denoted in percent.

For the regression I transformed the variable with the natural logarithm Ln(Y).

Now, I have a dummy variable which is significant and has the coefficient value of an IV = 0.03.

What does this mean?
If the IV is =1, then the log(Y) will increase by: (exp(0.03)-1)*100 = 3.05%.

But 3.05% im comparison to what?

For example:
The Y variable of my unit is 12%.
Is it then that it increases to 15%?
Or is it that it increases to 12%*1.03= 12.36%?

Comment: Percentage changes in percentages often cause confusion and ambiguity.  It might be less confusing to use decimals rather than percentages and to use multiplication rather than percentage changes.  So your first statements becomes "adding $1$ to $X$ multiplies the estimate of $Y$ by $\exp(B_1)$" and "if the IV is $1$, this multiplies the estimate of $Y$ by $1.0305$".  This makes it clearer that in your final line, the correct approach is $0.12 \times 1.03 = 0.1236$

Comment: Thank you very much Henry! Could you please tell me that it changes in comparison to what? Is it valid to say that, for example, if the mean of the Y variable is 50, the outcome of the regression suggest a 50%*1.0305= 0.51525 change for the average population? I also have a question and this sounds dumb, but this is the typical "end of assignment" hysteria: I have a fractional value as one IV, bound between 0 and 100, so basically also a percentage value. Is an increase in one then an increase from 0.03 to 0.04, or an increase from 0.03 to 1.03? latter would make an interpretation infeasible.